# Why i can not delete user log in in my database?

Tags: sql-server

i connect the sql server windows authentication and create a simple database and table on it,and so define the new log in user and set to sql server authentication,every thing is fine,but i connect the database with windows authentication too,i want to delete the windows authentication,and  i want just connect that database with only sql server authentication,this picture for that problem:
when i connect with sql server authentication,i define the rajabi user log in.
[image]

but i want just rajabi user can be connect to this database.how can i solve that?thanks.

Comment: The picture doesn't help at all. How did you create the account and what permissions did you give it? Did you create the account at the server level or only the database? If you don't give connection permissions to an account it *won't* be able to connect.

Comment: Please generate a script of the account you created at the server *and*database level. From the Server>Security>Logins list, right-click on the user and select `Script Login As Create`. The same at the database level, in `Security > Users`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What if any roles have you granted the new user?  Granting the reader role to the new user should allow said user to connect.

Right click on your user -> Properties -> Membership -> Anything checked? I usually check the db_datareader just to allow a user to connect.

Comment: no anything is check ,but i dont want to read my database,i want cant connect to my database,i want just rajabi connect this database

Comment: @behzadrazzaqi what does `connect` mean? Simply logging in isn't very useful if you can't perform any queries. Besides, you need to create the account at the server level *first* before it can connect to any database

Answer (score 1):

Please run on your database

```
DROP USER [UserAccount]    
CREATE USER [UserAccount] FOR LOGIN [UserAccount]    
EXEC sp_addrolemember N'db_owner', N'UserAccount'
```